# TinyMCE with div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tinymce

Below is my JSP code:

```
<tr>
      <td colspan="2">custEmail</td>
      <td colspan="5"><div id= "custEmail"><p><strong>Test</strong></p></div></td>
</tr>
```

Below is the code attaching the `div` with [TinyMCE Editor](http://www.tinymce.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        width : "640",
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "custEmail",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "preview",
        readonly : true,
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true
    });
</script>
```

But on my HTML page, I see the content as:

```
<p><strong>Test</strong></p>
```

Instead of Bold Test. As soon as I change the following:

```
div id="custEmail" tag to textarea id="custEmail"
```

It works fine. Not sure if I need to have some setting for div tag?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to set [forced_root_block](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block) to `'div'` :

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        forced_root_block : 'div'
});
```

Comment: Same result. Still i see <p><strong>Test</strong></p>

Comment: hmm, i see. can you give the class custEmail to the td?

Comment: still no impact <td colspan="5" class="custEmail">

Comment: hmmm, can you create a tinymce fiddle?

Comment: Thariama .Sorry i was  out of station for some time. I am holding on this requirement for now. Thanks for your reply