# Use div tag as a default instead of paragraph in tinymce

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce, joomla3.0

I'm new at joomla and currently using Joomla version 3.6. Is there a way to set the tinymce editor to use div tag as a default instead of paragraph? Any answer would be appreciated, Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585178/tinymce-with-div-tag

Answer (score 18):

You have to init tinymce with `forced-root-block: 'div'`.

```
tinymce.init({
  // ...
  forced_root_block : 'div'
});
```

> If you set this option to false it will never produce p tags on enter, or, automatically it will instead produce br elements and Shift+Enter will produce a p. — [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@forced_root_block/)